# Randomizing an array inside a ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, random, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of object which I use ng-repeat to iterate over. However, every object has 2 properties - a country (string) and cities (array). How can I randomize this array of cities on some button click or page refresh. An example:

```
$scope.package = [{
  country: 'Sweden',
  cities: ['aaa', 'bbb']
}, {
  country: 'Sudan',
  cities: ['yyy', 'zzz']
}]

$scope.showNext = function() {
  // shows next slide but randomize the cities
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="pack in package">
    <p>{{pack.country}}</p>
      <span>{{pack.cities}}</span> <!-- cities should be random value from the array -->
  </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="showNext()"> Next Country </button>
```

NOTE: It's not required that the button do the randomizing. The button just jumps to next country slide but that the cities name should be shuffled every time.

Comment: means cities should be displayed in different order every-time like (aaa,bbb,ccc or bbb,ccc,aaa, or aaa,ccc,bbb etc..)?

Comment: as the cities is an array, i can't put pack.cities[0] in the html as doing so will always be first city in array. So I want the value inside the [ ] to be random ( here 0 or 1 as there are only 2 elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a `randomize()` function to pick a random `city` in `cities`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="pack in package">
    <p>{{pack.country}}</p>
    <span>{{randomize(pack)}}</span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can try with the following snippet:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.package = [
        {country: 'Sweden', cities: ['aaa', 'bbb']}, 
        {country: 'Sudan', cities: ['yyy', 'zzz']}
    ];

    $scope.randomize = function(country) {
        return country.cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * country.cities.length)];
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="pack in package">
      <p>{{pack.country}}</p>
      <span>{{randomize(pack)}}</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I did `<span>{{city in pack.cities | orderBy: randomize}}</span>` but it gave me a  syntax error with the 'in'

Comment: Thanks.This is absolutely the right way to do it :))

Comment: I'm having a small issue as since I'm getting these packages asynchronously and the cities are infact images `<img ng-src="{{ }}">`, the value inside {{ }} is not being evaluated. Tried putting the randomize function inside the promise but not much is happening

Comment: Suggestion: `randomize` can save the displayed city in the scope (`$scope.country.displayed = country.cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * country.cities.length)];`. Call it for each country in the `.then` result of your promise.

Comment: If you make `Show console` true, then sometimes it will give digest error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use random function for random data and `limitTo` for only one random city.

**Updated:**
I have updated snippet, instead of calling random function from page (which will call function every-time when page refreshes), you can call it on page load and when you call next button.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.random = function() {
    return Math.random();
  }
  $scope.package = [{
    country: 'Sweden',
    cities: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
  }, {
    country: 'Sudan',
    cities: ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
  }]

  function generateRandom() {
    angular.forEach($scope.package, function(country) {
      country.random = country.cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * country.cities.length)];
    })
  }
  $scope.showNext = function() {
    generateRandom();
    // shows next slide but randomize the cities
  }
  generateRandom();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pack in package">
        <p>{{pack.country}}</p>
        <span>{{pack.random}}</span>
        <!-- <span>{{pack.cities|orderBy:random|limitTo:1}}</span> -->
        <!-- cities should be random value from the array -->
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="showNext()"> Next Country </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes, your code break: `"message": "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$rootSco...`.

Comment: This error seems to happen to me on all cases. The application still works so yeah but just anxious to see infinite digest error :)

Comment: thanks manshi for the answer. learned about `limitTo` today :))

Comment: Hi, I have updated snippet, please check. Also now you wont get any error. In Mistalis code also if you make `Show console` true, then it will give error.